# Making automatic phone call

Tags: phone-call, tapi

I need to write a program to make automatic phone calls to given numbers. How to do that. What libraries do I need.

Would prefer Unix-like, c++/java/python way.

Comment: what type (make/model) of phone? Does the app need to run on the/a (mobile) phone?

Comment: You've taggedd this `tapi` which is a Microsoft library but you're asking for a *nix solution? What gives? and what have you tried?

Comment: i misunderstood tapi as something else. Basically, i need a solution to make calls through a connected phone/mobile. The app can be on the mobile or on pc.

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking at the open source Asterix solution http://www.asterisk.org/

Comment: That requires specialized hardware. I just have a mobile phone or a normal telephone set. How about these?